# How to implicitly convert to common super types in F# pattern matches?

Tags: f#, type-inference

**Problem Summary**

At the moment when using f# I must explicitly coerce a value to the parent type of its type in order to get pattern matching expressions to type check correctly.   I would ideally like a neater way of doing.

**Example**

Suppose I have some class hierachy:

```
type Foo () =
    abstract member Value : unit -> string

type A (i:int) = 
    inherit Foo ()
        override this.Value () = i.ToString()

type B (s:string) = 
    inherit Foo ()
        override this.Value () = s
```

Ideally, and in some programming languages in normally, I would write the equivalent of the following:

```
let bar (i:int) : Foo =
    match i with
      | 1 -> B "one"
      | _ -> A i
```

However this fails to type check correctly, giving me the error, "This expression was expected to have type Foo but here has type B".  I don't understand why the compiler doesn't have enough information to infer a common super type for the match expression and then check that the common super type is 'Foo'.

At present I am forced to provide an explicit coercion for every case in the pattern match:

```
let bar2 (i:int) : Foo =
    match i with
      | 1 -> (B "one") :> Foo
      | _ -> (A i) :> Foo
```

I would like to avoid this.

**Further Notes**

- Intuition suggests that this is a result of a more general issue.  I would have thought though that something as common as pattern matching, or if statements which also exhibit the same property, would have a type checking rule to account for common super types.
- Before anyone suggests - I appreciate that if A or B were Object Expressions this would work, but my real example is creating instances of C# classes where they are normal classes.
- Is there a way for me to declare functions to implicitly convert types, as for example scala has, so I could apply automatic conversions for the module where I'm doing this generation?

Thanks for any help on this matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `upcast`, a la

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type Foo () = 
    abstract member Value : unit -> string 

type A (i:int) =  
    inherit Foo () 
    override this.Value () = i.ToString() 

type B (s) =  
    inherit Foo () 
    override this.Value () = s 

let bar2 i : Foo = 
    match i with 
    | 1 -> upcast B "one"
    | _ -> upcast A i
```

You still have to add it to every branch, but this is often preferable to casting to the type, since often the typename is like 20 or 30 characters long (`MyNamespace.ThisThingy`), whereas `upcast` is just 6 characters.

But, briefly, the language rules don't allow for anything else, the types of all the branches have to be equal.

Comment: The reason the type checker doesn't do any shenanigans with derived types is that first it would make the type checking step more complicated and second it would allow you to introduce subtle bugs. For example, consider the following:

    match i with
    | 1 -> B("one")
    | 2 -> "stuff"

Well, both System.String and B share common base type System.Object, so the result of that match expression is of type obj. Which is 99.9% not what you wanted.

Comment: True, though in the specific instance the OP is asking about, he has already declared the function return type as `: Foo`, so I think maybe it would not be completely unreasonable for the inferencer to use this as a greatest-lower-bound or something.  I have not thought through all the implications of that, though.

Comment: I think that `x :> _` reads better than `upcast x`, but maybe that's just me.  The branches of the match don't line up as well, though.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen this question a couple of times before, but I just realized that there is quite an interesting way to workaround the issue (without any significant negative effects such as big runtime overhead).

You can use a very simple *computation expression* that has only `Return` member. The builder will have a type parameter and `Return` will expect values of this type. The trick is, that F# *does* insert automatic upcasts when calling a member. Here is the declaration:

```
type ExprBuilder<'T>() =
  member x.Return(v:'T) = v

let expr<'T> = ExprBuilder<'T>()
```

To write a simple pattern matching that returns anything as `obj`, you can now write:

```
let foo a = expr<obj> {
  match a with
  | 0 -> return System.Random()
  | _ -> return "Hello" }
```

You still have to be explicit about the return type (when creating the computation expression), but I find the syntax quite neat (but it is definitely a tricky use that could confuse people who'll see it for the first time).

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but I still have to have syntax on every line of the pattern match.  Still - this is definitely the best solution I've seen yet!

Comment: @Brian: I'll take that as a compliment :-), but you're right, it is probably too tricky (and I wrote that in the last sentence) although it always depends on the type of project - Is it some C#/F# plumbing code or a core part of a complex F# system? In some cases, tricky solutions should be allowed :-). And after all, _asynchronous workflows_ are tricky too (in a sense).

Comment: There's nothing more fun than finding some unexpected use for a language construct.  As this example shows, there are uncharted depths to the combination of workflows and objects. The secret, I think, is to gradually build up the educational level of F# programmers until people are *not* confused on first encountering constructs like this. The C++ community underwent a similar evolution in the 90's.