# Does F# handle inheritance differently compared to C# when type parameters are covariant?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I hit something new to me with the following piece of code when following the equivalent in C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555149/why-is-not-oncompleted-not-called-in-this-suspendable-implementation-rx-pausab). The compiler gives multiple errors basically telling the [IConnectableObservable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211887(v=vs.103).aspx) created in `source.Publish()` does not match `IObservable` even though it derives from it (according to the MSDN article linked).

Is there something in F# that is different with regard to C# concerning inheritance in this case or can someone provider pointers as to what is going on? Have I just made a typo I can't see? What comes to the heading regarding covariance, it's just a wild guess as I'm at least temporarily out of ideas. And so, maybe writing somewhere may help me and others...

One example of the many error messages:

> No overloads match for method 'Create'. The available overloads are shown below (or in the Error List window).
>
> No overloads match for method 'Switch'. The available overloads are shown below (or in the Error List window).
>
> Error Possible overload: '(extension) IObservable.Switch<'TSource>() :
>   IObservable<'TSource>'. Type constraint mismatch. The type 
>       IObservable<IConnectableObservable<'b>>     is not compatible with type
>       IObservable<IObservable<'a>>     The type 'IObservable<'a>' does not match the type 'IConnectableObservable<'b>'.

```
open System.Reactive.Concurrency
open System.Reactive.Disposables
open System.Reactive.Subjects
open System.Reactive.Linq


type Observable with
    static member inline Suspendable(source: IObservable<_>, suspend: IObservable<bool>, isSuspendedInitially: bool): IObservable<_> =
        Observable.Create<_>(fun observer ->
            let shared = source.Publish()
            let pausable =
                suspend.StartWith(isSuspendedInitially)
                    .TakeUntil(shared.LastOrDefaultAsync())
                    .DistinctUntilChanged()
                    .Select(fun p -> if p then shared else Observable.Empty<_>())
                    .Switch()
            new CompositeDisposable(pausable.Subscribe(observer), shared.Connect()))
```

The corresponding C# code

```cs
public static class RxExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<T> Suspendable<T>(this IObservable<T> stream, IObservable<bool> suspend, bool isSuspendedInitially)
    {            
        return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
        {
            var shared = stream.Publish();
            var pausable = suspend
                .StartWith(isSuspendedInitially)
                .TakeUntil(shared.LastOrDefaultAsync())
                .DistinctUntilChanged()
                .Select(p => p ? shared : Observable.Empty<T>())
                .Switch();
            return new CompositeDisposable(pausable.Subscribe(o), shared.Connect());                
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bit tricky, but you need to add two upcasts: `shared` to `IObservable<_>`, and the result of the lambda function to `IDisposable`. These would be implicit in C#, but need to be explicit in F#:

```ml
type Observable with
    static member inline Suspendable (source: IObservable<_>, 
                                      suspend: IObservable<bool>, 
                                      isSuspendedInitially: bool): IObservable<'a> =
        Observable.Create<_>(fun observer ->
            let shared = source.Publish()
            let pausable = 
                suspend.StartWith(isSuspendedInitially)
                    .TakeUntil(shared.LastOrDefaultAsync())
                    .DistinctUntilChanged()
                    .Select(fun p -> if p then shared :> IObservable<_> 
                                          else Observable.Empty<_>())
                    .Switch()
            new CompositeDisposable(pausable.Subscribe(observer), 
                                    shared.Connect()) :> IDisposable)
```

Comment: Ah, that was it then! I think I missed the cast to IDisposable as I think I tried a cast to IObservable (well, late at night etc.). One lives and learns. I can't check this before the evening, but this must be it! With a quick search I found [How to implicitly convert to common super types in F# pattern matches?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909359/how-to-implicitly-convert-to-common-super-types-in-f-pattern-matches), which brings additional aspects and techniques to handle this situation. I believe it could have wider interest.